# PHPseclib crashes while trying to upload via SFTP

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I´ve written a tool using PHPseclibs SFTP solution to uplaod various files to different target server. All targetserver are using wingFTP.

Under some conditions the upload fails without giving any debug message or error code.

I could figure out that the error (if it occures) allways occures in the following line of my code:

```
[...]
if(!$sftp->put($aResult[0]["targetpath"] . $sFilename, EXPORTFOLDER . "/" . $sFilename, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE)){
[...]
```

Is there any way to see what is happening? There are no error messages or something... can I configure debug/error messages while using PHPseclib somewhere?

In about 95% of all cases the Upload is successfull and it does not only appear on one target server or for one file. Does someone have an idea where the problem could be located?

Comment: What does it mean "crashes"?

Comment: PHP crash without any message. The tool is running on the CLI. If the error occures the tool stops, no debug messages in log or database.

Comment: How big are the files you're uploading? I'd enable real-time logging. `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 3)` or `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 4)`. If you set it to 4 you'll also need to set `NET_SSH2_LOG_REALTIME_FILENAME` to the name of the logfile. eg. `define('NET_SSH2_LOG_REALTIME_FILENAME', '/path/to/file.txt');`

Comment: The files are (currently) between 21 and 1811699 bytes. The files failing are mostly bewteen 50000 and 300000 bytes, so it does not rely on the filesize in my oppinion. I´ve added logging as suggested, I´ll update as soon as I´ve some log entrys.

Comment: I think https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/pull/1026 might be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I updated to version 2 of phpseclib. First tests were all successfull so it might be fixed now. I´ll post an update in a few days after some "real" exports habe been send with the tool.